# Oracle Date function is slow

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a very large table that is used to collect statistics, and I am running the below to collect a sections of date, nothing is returned and is very slow

```
SELECT * FROM ABC.STATISTIC
where ABS.FUNCTION = 'XX'
and trunc(QMS_TIMESTAMP) >= to_date('2015/08/20','yyyy/mm/dd')
and trunc(QMS_BUSINESS_DAY) <= to_date('2015/08/31','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Also doing a `SELECT * FROM ABC.STATISTIC` returns rows to aqua data studio with max results set to perhaps 100.

Any ideas to query using the data function? Also the table only has a index on a ID columns not on date.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question. Show us your complete stored procedure (or function)

Comment: Hi- this is not a function, just a simple query to extract data from a table

Comment: What is `ABS.FUNCTION`? Is it a PL/SQL function? If so, that is probably a big contributor to your performance issue.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest rewriting the query as:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM ABC.STATISTIC s
WHERE ABS.FUNCTION = 'XX' AND
      QMS_TIMESTAMP >= DATE '2015-08-20' AND
      QMS_BUSINESS_DAY < DATE '2015-09-01';
```

Then, the best index for this query is probably `STATISTIC(FUNCTION, QMS_TIMESTAMP, QMS_BUSINESS_DAY)`.

Comment: Would like to create a index, however this a long process of change process.  Tried the query with no result

Answer (score 0):

You can try out these 2 things in Aqua Data Studio
1. Enable Client Statistics by choosing the menu option Query > Show Client Statistics and then execute the slow running query. This will show where the slowdown is occurring.
2. Enable the Visual Explain Plan results tab by choosing the menu option Query > Show Execution Plan. You can then see whether the explain plan indicates any bottlenecks. Visual explain plan documentation:
https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation15/page/125/Visual-Explain-Plan